# NuGet always thinks a package needs updating

Tags: .net, nuget

Whenever I *Manage NuGet Packages* for the Visual Studio solution I'm currently working on, it always says that a particular package needs updating.

However, when I press *Update* for the package, I'm not allowed to choose which projects to update it for:
[image: Select Projects window showing all of the projects in read-only state]

When I press *OK* to proceed, nothing happens; the window just closes and leaves me with the *Manage NuGet packages* window again, still showing that this particular package has an update available.

This only seems to occur for one particular package in the solution. Allow of the projects that reference this package already reference the latest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Workaround

I noticed that an old, unused version of the library was sitting in the solution's *packages* folder. I uninstalled it by using the following command in  *Package Manager Console*:

```
Uninstall-Package PackageName -Version PackageVersion
```

Note that you need to substitute the exact package name and version in the above command.

Alternatively, you could probably also just delete the package from the packages folder.

Note that this doesn't address *why* the problem happened in the first place or how to prevent it.

Comment: I noticed that when I went to uninstall some of the packages it would complain that another package depended on it despite having another higher level version that satisfied the dependency.  I think this might be a clue to how it got in a messed up state.